# Vanilo Laravel 7 error 403 - Forbidden in http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/customer

Tags: php, e-commerce, laravel-7, vanilo

I'm trying to create an e-commerce application from scratch with Vanilo. I've meticulously followed the steps described [here](https://vanilo.io/docs/1.2/installation) several times. However, when it comes to accessing the route in the example `http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/customer`, I get a 403 Forbidden error. I've tried many things but this is what I have right now in my concord.php file.

```php
return [
    'modules' => [
        Konekt\AppShell\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider::class => [
            'ui' => [
                'name' => 'Vanilo',
                'url' => '/admin/product'
            ]
        ],
        Vanilo\Framework\Providers\ModuleServiceProvider::class => [
            'image' => [
                'variants' => [
                    'thumbnail' => [
                        'width' => 250,
                        'height' => 188,
                        'fit' => 'fill'
                    ],
                    'medium' => [
                        'width' => 540,
                        'height' => 406,
                        'fit' => 'fill'
                    ]
                ]
            ],
        ]
    ]
];
```

My user has the role of admin in the database.

How can I access this route?

Comment: Can you access other areas of the admin section?

Answer (score 1):

While creating initial user using `php artisan appshell:super` keep the role default `admin`

After creating the user check the role_permissions table. the role must have all the permissions.